# MVC Preserving Model When Jumping Between Controller and Forms

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, models

so I recently started  project in .net MVC and have been having issues preserving data. I read somewhere that in order to do so, you have to pass the model back and forth. I tried doing this, but it still runs into issues. In my project, I have two buttons right now, getData and getData2. My view prints their true/false values. When I press one, it turns true, but if I press the other, it turns true but the other one goes to false. I want them both to stay true if I press them both.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData(TestSite.Models.FarModels theFars)
{      
    theFars.HasData = true;
    return RedirectToAction("FarCalc",theFars);             
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData2(TestSite.Models.FarModels theFars)
{
    theFars.HasData2 = true;
    return RedirectToAction("FarCalc", theFars);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FarCalc(TestSite.Models.FarModels theFars)
{                                
    return View(theFars);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))

   {

    //@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FarValue)

    <input type="submit" value="GetData" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetData2", "Home", FormMethod.Post))

{

    //@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FarValue)

    <input type="submit" value="GetData2" />
}

@Model.HasData
@Model.HasData2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make use of TempData object because the use of RedirectToAction returns a status code of 302, and the model binding does not exist.  A good example is below.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/842080/How-to-Persist-Data-with-TempData-in-MVC